# Trying to use django pagination I get this error "TemplateDoesNotExist at /videos/"

Tags: python, django, pagination

I keep getting the following error message trying to use pagination in Django. I have tried and tried but can't seem to figure this out. Was gonna do without it but a modern site needs pagination.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /videos/
```

this is what I have in my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


from .models import Video


def index(request):
    page = "video/index.html"
    title = "Video"
    # videos = Video.objects.all()

    videos_list = Video.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(videos_list, 25)  # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        videos = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:

        videos = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:

        videos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        "videos": videos,
        "title": title,
    }
    return render(request, page, context)
```

this is what I have in my video/index

```
{% block content %}
<div id="content"><h1 style="color: #f5f5f5; margin:0">Video index</h1></div>

{% for r in videos %}

    <div class="index-box">
        <div >
            <img src="{{ r.img }}" style="width:241px; height: 200px">
        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'video:detail' r.slug %}">
            <h5 style="margin-left: 10px ">{{ r.title |truncatechars:15}}</h5>
        </a>
    </div>

{% endfor %}




<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if videos.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ videos.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ videos.number }} of {{ videos.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if videos.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ videos.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

my file structure

```
video
   |-migrations
   |-static
   |-templates
        |-includes
        |-video
            |-detail.html
            |-index.html
```

How can I correct this to make this work? Any and all help is welcome. I have tried to modify what was in the docs to suit my needs but I don't know where I'm going wrong at.

Comment: I think it shouldn't have anything to do with pagination, it's just that django couldn't find your html file. What's your file structure look like?

Comment: @ShangWang See above

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `page` 2 times.

```
def index(request):
    **page = "video/index.html"**
    title = "Video"
    # videos = Video.objects.all()

    videos_list = Video.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(videos_list, 25)  # Show 25 contacts per page

    **page = request.GET.get('page')**
    try:
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. the

```
page = "video/index.html"
```

wasn't being read. I had to move it from the top to the bottom

so I went from this

```
page = "video/index.html" <------------(not being read)
title = "Video"
# videos = Video.objects.all()

videos_list = Video.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(videos_list, 25)  # Show 25 contacts per page

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    videos = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:

    videos = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:

    videos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

context = {
    "videos": videos,
    "title": title,
}
return render(request, page, context) <-------(page has no value)
```

to

def index(request):

```
title = "Video"
# videos = Video.objects.all()

videos_list = Video.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(videos_list, 2)  # Show 25 contacts per page

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    videos = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:

    videos = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:

    videos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

page = "video/index.html" <------------(being read)
context = {
    "videos": videos,
    "title": title,

}
return render(request, page, context) <------------(page has value)
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `page` for the page number and template name in the same view. It would be better to rename `template = "video/index.html"`, then `return render(request, template, context)`. That way, the position of `template = "video/index.html"` does not matter.